# move files to s3 in EC2

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I have S3 bucket in EC2 . I want to remove multiple files between s3 folders . however it showing deleted files but files are still there

command:

aws s3  rm s3://mybucket/path1/publish/test/dummyfile_*.dat

got below message

delete: s3://mybucket/path1/publish/test/dummyfile_*.dat,. But file is still present

can anyone please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to delete multiple files in S3 bucket with AWS CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733318/how-to-delete-multiple-files-in-s3-bucket-with-aws-cli)

Answer (score 0):

"Amazon S3 offers eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS and DELETES in all Regions."
from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#CoreConcepts

If you make a copy of a S3 object to an EC2 instance, you simply made a copy of it.
You can use `aws s3 sync` to synchronize S3 objects (files) between S3 and your EC2 instance, see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html