# Delete folder in Amazon S3 using the Amazon S3 API

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-cli

While I am aware that I can delete folder using `aws s3 rm s3://xyz/abc --recursive` to delete folder contents but I want to know how to do the same using `aws s3api`.

Comment: s3api has delete-objects which does not utilize --recursive.  You'd need to create a list of the objects to be deleted and feed it into xargs.  It's possible but will take some fiddling.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41733318/how-to-delete-multiple-files-in-s3-bucket-with-aws-cli) and [this one](https://serverfault.com/questions/679989/most-efficient-way-to-batch-delete-s3-files)

Comment: @kenlukas right. That is what I thought too. Was worth the shot.

Comment: @jarmod I mean using `s3api`

Comment: Why do you want to do this via `aws s3api` which is a lower level awscli capability than `aws s3`?